# Transparently handling a numeric type as a single-valued sequence (or vice-versa)

Tags: python, functional-programming, sequence

I'm starting to learn Python by writing an ODE solver. I would like to handle transparently both one- or many-variable input functions. Here is my code for one step of Euler's method:

```
def euler(h, t, y, f):
    return (y + h*f for y,f in zip(y,f(t,y)))
```

Now I define two functions, `f1` and `f2` like this:

```
def f1(t,y):
    return -2*t*y

def f2(t,y):
    x, y = y #is rebinding usually ok, or confusing?
    return (x - t*y, y + x/t)
```

When I test them, that's what (obviously) happens

```
>>> list(euler(0.01, 1, (1,2), f2))
[0.99, 2.03]
>>> list(euler(0.01, 1, 1, f1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in euler
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

I would like the solver to handle transparently if the function given works on one or more variables, but haven't found a cool way to do it. A way I found was

```
import operator as op
def euler(h, t, y, f):
    if op.isNumberType(y):
        return (y + h*f(t,y),)
    return (y + h*f for y,f in zip(y,f(t,y)))
```

But now I passed a float and returned an iterable, so `list(euler(...))` can suceed. However, I can't call, for example, `f(t,euler(...))`.

Is there a way to handle a singleton sequence as a primitive type, or a primitive as a singleton sequence without endless checking? By "endless checking" I mean, having to check just in a few places, and not all over my code. Or should I just suck it up and make `f(t,y)` expects a sequence instead of a numeric?

Thanks for any help, and tips about my coding are welcome, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to make f(t, y) use sequence only:

```
def euler(h, t, y, f):
    return (y + h*v for y,v in zip(y,f(t,y)))

def f1(t,status):
    x, = status
    return -2*t*x,

def f2(t,status):
    x, y = status
    return x - t*y, y + x/t


print list(euler(0.01, 1, (1,2), f2))
print list(euler(0.01, 1, (1,), f1))
```

Comment: How is your answer different from mine?

Comment: there is a comma after x in f1.

Comment: I liked @HYRY's best, as it evidences the similarities between their uses. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

In your euler function, you can catch TypeError and recover by encapsulating in a list and trying again.

Comment: Is `try...catch` preferred over `if`? In Java (yeah, I know, "Java is not Python") it's best practice to use exceptions in exceptional conditions only.

Comment: Yes, look up "duck-typing" got more details.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to write your euler function in the following manner

```
def euler(h, t, y, f):
    if isinstance(y,collections.Iterable):
        return (y + h*f for y,f in zip(y,f(t,y)))
    else:
        return (y+h*f(t,y),)
```

Another solution is to write your one dimensional function as

```
def f1(t,y):
    return (-2*t*y[0],)
```

and then call euler in the following manner

```
list(euler(0.01, 1, (1,), f1))
```